# SQL Select different values from same object

Tags: sql

i have the following table:

```
---------------
Name       Tel      
John       1234
John       1234
John       1000
Test       9999
```

How can count distinct phone nubers from all persons in SQL ?

Excepcted result:

```
---------------
Name       count
John       2
Test       1
```

Comment: With that table data, what is the expected result?

Comment: Hint:  `select distinct`.

Comment: Edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this. Use `DISTINCT` in `COUNT` function and `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT Name,COUNT(DISTINCT Tel)
FROM T 
GROUP BY Name
```

*sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ea45c/4*

Comment: That's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Tel FROM myTable WHERE Name='John'
```